# How to use a variable as a field in mongodb .find?

Tags: node.js

My data in mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : "5a5ffef0869422169c7aa01b",
    "name" : "Some One", 
    "time" : "2018-1-31 11:59"
}
```

I have a query command

```
test.find({"time":"2018-1-31 11:59"}).toArray(function (err,data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

and I want to retrieve the data querying on a field time passed as a variable.

But it not work:

```
 // my code ....
    var input = yy +"-"+mm+"-"+dd+" "+hh+":"+minute;
    var text = "time";
    test.find({ text : input }).toArray(function (err,data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(data);
            });
```

How can I query mongodb keeping both field name and its value dynamic?

Comment: `test.find({ [text] : input })` try it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.